# How do I apply a list of translations to the same object?

Tags: openscad

imagine I have a list of translations which I want to apply to the same object.

for instance, a list which defines rotation and translation

```
list = [[10,20],[30,45]]
```

how to I apply them in a for loop to one object?

I am looking for something like

```
for (i=list) {
   translate([i[0],0,0])
   rotate([i[1],0,0])
}
cube([10,1,1]);
```

obviously, that is the wrong approach...

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by defining a module that steps through the list recursively.

```
list = [[10,20],[30,45]];

module transform(list, idx = 0) {
    if (idx >= len(list)) {
        children();
    } else {
        translate([list[idx][0],0,0])
            rotate([list[idx][1],0,0])
                transform(list, idx + 1)
                    children();
    }
}

transform(list) cube([10,1,1]);
```